# Another method cannot be called frominside vue.js component while using vue-multiselect and debounce

Tags: vuejs2, debouncing

I am trying to implement to make autocomplete using vue-multiselect and it has asynchronous server call but I have used the debounce function to delay the call in the server but I am having the problem . The problem is I am not able to call another method from the method where I am using debounce . 
I have the code as follows :

```
 <script>
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';
import _ from 'lodash';
export default {
    name: "required-information",
    components:{
        Multiselect
    },
    data(){
        return {
            tripType:1,
            depart_date:null,
            return_date:null,
            selectedAirport:null,
            depart_from_airports:[],
            selectedToAirport:null,
            depart_to_airports:[],
            adults:null,
            children_no:null,
            flight_class:null,
            infants:null,
            airlines:[],
            selectedAirline:[],
        }
    },
    methods:{

        formatAirport:()=>{
            console.log("q");
            // let new_airports=[];
            // for(let i=0;i<airports.length;i++){
            //     let city=airports[i].airport+' ('+airports[i].code+')';
            //     let push_data={
            //         name:city,
            //         code:response[i].code
            //     }
            //     new_airports.push(push_data)
            // }
            // return new_airports;
        },
        asyncFind: _.debounce(query => {

            if(!query)
                return;



           axios.get("/airport-list?query="+query).then((response)=>{
               this.formatAirport();

           }).catch((error)=>{
               console.log(error);
           })
        }, 1000),

    }
}
```

Instead of logging the q it shows the error as :

```
TypeError: _this.formatAirport is not a function
at app.js:66754
at <anonymous>
```

I have called asyncFind from the following line of code

```
                     <multiselect v-model="selectedAirport" id="depart_form"  track-by="name" label="name" placeholder="Select one" :options="depart_from_airports" :searchable="true" @search-change="asyncFind" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use arrow (=>) function you won't be able to access data properties of any other external properties. Use regular function way like the one in below:

```
asyncFind: _.debounce(function(query) {
            if(!query)
                return;
           axios.get("/airport-list?query="+query).then((response)=>{
               this.formatAirport();
           }).catch((error)=>{
               console.log(error);
           })
        }, 1000),
```

Hope this helps.